# C++: ieee float binary data: output to screen the values

Tags: binary

I have a file of IEEE binary data (floats).  I know visual doesn't require conversion, hopefully GCC also uses IEEE format for floats?
My task is to take all the data values stored in the binary file, and output them to the console.  I am thinking I should read the numbers into an array then cout the array.  The tough part is getting the numbers into the array.  I am thinking to use reinterpret_cast, because I guess the  C++ read function only works if you use pointers to char's -.-